# Designing asp.net core web api to add sub classes/specialized objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, design-patterns, asp.net-core-webapi

I have not worked with EF for a while.
As an exercise, I am writing a `core web api` that allows keeping track of a user medias.
A media can be a postcard, a photo album, a recording, a book...

I would like to know what is the way to go/best practice in writing the Add (createMedia) method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Add(Media media)
```

My model is comprised of several specific classes representing one type of media - like Postcard, Photoalbum, recording, etc. In addition, there is a Media type - which contains shared properties among all media types:

```
public class Media
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public MediaType Type { get; set; }
    public bool InUse { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; } //yyyy-mm-dd
    public string Owner { get; set; }
}
```

As an example of one of the specific media types:

```
public class Postcard
{
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public int MediaId { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }

}
```

I designed my `EntityFramework` db to consist of a 1-1 relation between Media and the relevant specific media table.

What is the best practice in writing the Add method ? Should it receive a Media object, and based on `MediaType` create the respective type ? I started with this approach, and had the action receive a second parameter named `detailsJson`, which I would parse and fill the respective object using reflection, but figured out that `POST` binding will not bind 2 objects.

I'm not well versed in design patterns.
Should there exist as many AddBook, AddPostcard... as many media types ?
I understand all models should be `POCO objects`, without inheritance.
I read about `DTOs`, but does not see how it helps me here.

Comment: Along with signaling the question should be closed because it lacks details, should one not mention which details are missing ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the Postcard and Book although both media types, they have different properties? for example, From, To, Place fields will not be there in book, whereas Book might have ISBN, Author, Genre etc.

so essentially they are different POCO objects altogether, media type is just a relationship they have in common

In this case, it's OK to have separate Add methods like AddBook, AddPostcard etc.

Update:

The individual POCO objects can refer to Media type to avoid duplicating same properties, same as underlying entity relationship

```
public class Postcard
{
    public Media Media { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Will each of the POCO objects repeat the shared properties, such as Title, Description, Date... ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing so far :)

Answer (score 0):

What about having a Key-Value table?

```
public class MediaValue {
    public string MediaId {get;set;}
    public string AttributeName {get;set;}
    public string AttributeValue{get;set;}
    //the key is the couple MediaId - AttributeName
}

public class Media {
   //shared properties
   public MediaType MediaType {get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<MediaValue> Attributes {get;set;}
}

public enum MediaType {
    PostCard, PhotoAlbum, ....
}
```

then you could add the DTOs foreach mediatype

```
public abstract class MediaDTO {
     //shared properties
}

public class PostCardDTO : MediaDTO {
    public string PostCardSpecificAttribute {get;set;} // this.PostCardCustomAttribute = aMediaDbObject.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeName == "PostCardSpecificAttribute");
}
```